# Measuring startup time in Java (statically inited code)

Tags: java, performance, static, startup

So my program needs to read a bunch of statements (10,000s) from txt files at startup, I was thinking of making a program that wrote all these statements as statically inited code that I can put into my program (mostly hash maps). But I haven't found a way to measure startup time in Java, so not sure how much the savings will be. Anyone knows either how to measure it, or how effective static initialization is?

Comment: Static initialization doesn't occur until the class is used, so if you put all your "statements" *(not to be confused with Java code, which is also called statements)* into a class other than the class with `main()`, you control *when* initialization occurs. So, this has nothing to do with Java program startup, since the startup will have completed by the time you load your statements, either from file or from class, and those can both be measured normally, since they are both triggered by a Java statement.

Comment: Thanks! This explains a lot I guess, how Java can start up fast even with large libraries included.